# Will let statements bloat Babel-transpiled code?

Tags: ecmascript-6, var, babeljs, let

Eslint recommends using `let` instead of `var`.  But I'm assuming that Babel transpiles `let` into a `function() {...}` or something similar, which could lead to a lot of bloat if I'm using `let` everywhere.  Does anyone know?  Should I be concerned?

Comment: Have you just tried it out? No, Babel does normally not transpile `let` to a function.

Comment: It'll only use a function when necessary, like for loops with captured variables.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it transpiles pretty efficiently:

Original:

```
for (let a = 0; a < 5; a++) {

}

for (let a = 1; a < 5; a++) {

}

var a = 7;

console.log(a);
```

Transpiled:

```
for (var _a = 0; _a < 5; _a++) {}

for (var _a2 = 1; _a2 < 5; _a2++) {}

var a = 7;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: how does the underscore keep the variables block scoped?

Comment: @DavidC Ah, it's not the underscore, it's the variable renaming.  Notice in the original code there are three different `a` variables, and in the transpiled code one has been renamed to `_a` and another to `_a2` so that they don't conflict.  I guess using underscores was just a Babel design decision.

Comment: Ah I see. I did not notice they were all different.